# How can I calculate the hours of difference between two timezones in nodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, date

How can I calculate the difference between UTC (that I generate with new Date()) and European Standard time?

Something like

```
const amsterdam = new Date('Europe/Amsterdam')
amsterdam.getTimezoneOffset() // returns the minutes of offset in this case 60
```

I can't simply use 1 hour since the time shifts in the winter and summer! :(

Comment: The offset at which date and time? As `Europe/Amsterdam` uses daylight saving time, the UTC offset is not always the same.

Comment: That is exactly what my problem is! Otherwise I could've just added the fixed difference on top ofcourse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I eventually ended up doing and what worked perfectly for me was the following

```js
      const timezoneOffsetInHours =
      moment().tz('Europe/Amsterdam').hour() - new Date().getHours()
```

This returns the hours that Amsterdam is ahead of UTC.

Comment: This will cause issues across dates (if timezone is one hour ahead and the current time is 23:30). Should use unix time instead and divide by 1 hour in seconds (3600): `(moment().tz('Europe/Amsterdam').unix() - moment().unix()) / 3600`

Answer (score 2):

You can get the offset for a particular location for any date using [*Intl.DateTimeFormat*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat) with suitable options, e.g.

```js
/* @param {string} loc - IANA representative location
 * @param {Date} date - default to current date
 * @returns {string} offset as ±H[mm]
 */
function getOffsetForLoc(loc, date = new Date()) {
  // Use Intl.DateTimeFormat to get offset
  let opts = {hour: 'numeric', timeZone: loc, timeZoneName:'short'};
  let getOffset = lang =>  new Intl.DateTimeFormat(lang, opts)
    .formatToParts(date)
    .reduce((acc, part) => {
      acc[part.type] = part.value;
      return acc;
    }, {}).timeZoneName;
  let offset = getOffset('en');
  // If offset is an abbreviation, change language
  if (!/^UCT|GMT/.test(offset)) {
    offset = getOffset('fr');
  }
  // Remove GMT/UTC 
  return offset.substring(3);
}

// Get current offsets for following locations
['Europe/Amsterdam',
 'America/New_York',
 'Asia/Kolkata']
  .forEach(loc => console.log(`${loc} : ${getOffsetForLoc(loc)}`));

// Get offsets in Amsterdam
[new Date(2021,0),  // 1 Jan 2021
 new Date(2021,5)   // 1 Jun 2021
].forEach(d => console.log(`Offset for Amsterdam on ${d.toLocaleDateString()} ${getOffsetForLoc('Europe/Amsterdam', d)}`));
```

Answer (score 0):

For others that are looking for a solution using luxon,

```
const {DateTime} = require('luxon');

const shortOffset = DateTime.utc().setZone('Europe/Amsterdam').toFormat('ZZ');
// +01:00 

const narrowOffset = DateTime.utc().setZone('Europe/Amsterdam').toFormat('Z');
// +1

const techieOffset = DateTime.utc().setZone('Europe/Amsterdam').toFormat('ZZZ');
//  +0100
```